# How to identify all the loaded ftplugins for the current file?

Tags: plugin-system

I have installed a lot of plugins and each may has its own ftplugin settings. What is the way to find out all ftplugin scripts that have been sourced for the current buffer?

---

Just to summarize the solution based on the accepted answer:

```
:exe 'filter #ftplugin/' . &filetype . '.vim$# scriptnames'
```

Comment: Actually, it's little bit more complex than that.
For instance, in C++, C ftplugins will also get loaded. Somehow, @Jim's answer took that into account, but also returned autoloaded plugins.

Comment: Also, if you work in C and on CSS, the command will also keep `ftplugin/css.vim` for instance. It depends on whether false positive are acceptable or not.

Comment: @Luc Hermitte, you are completely right. So the question is still open. Is there a way to withdraw the acceptance?

Comment: @LucHermitte, I modified the answer so that your second concern is solved. The first one I have no  idea and is still waiting for some experts to solve

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know of a direct way to get a list of only the things loaded for the current buffer based on filetype, but `:scriptnames` will list everything that's been loaded, including system/default plugins, runtime scripts, etc.

To figure out what's additionally autoloaded for a specific filetype, start Vim with no arguments, run `:scriptnames`, then open a file of the type you care about, and run `:scriptnames` again. If anything new was autoloaded for the filetype, you'll see it appended to the list the second time.

You can capture the output (to paste into a buffer, for example) with `redir`:

```
:redir @a
:scriptnames
:redir END
```

You'll see the output displayed, but it will also be copied to register `a`. You can paste that into a buffer with `"ap`.

Comment: Thanks @Jim Stewart. Based on your answer, I fount the solution: `:exe 'filter #ftplugin/' . &filetype . '# scriptnames'`.

Answer (score 4):

A manual way might be to use [script debugging](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/repeat.txt.html#debug-scripts). Edit a file with the `:debug` command, say `:debug e foo.c`. Then set breakpoints for all `.vim` files using `breakadd file *.vim`. Repeatedly issue the `:cont` command:

```
Entering Debug mode.  Type "cont" to continue.
cmd: e foo.c
>breakadd file *.vim
"foo.c" [New File]
Breakpoint in "/usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.0.1171/share/vim/vim80/ftplugin/c.vim" line 1
/usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.0.1171/share/vim/vim80/ftplugin/c.vim
line 7: if exists("b:did_ftplugin")
> c
Breakpoint in "/usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.0.1171/share/vim/vim80/indent/c.vim" line 1
/usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.0.1171/share/vim/vim80/indent/c.vim
line 7: if exists("b:did_indent")
>
Breakpoint in "/usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.0.1171/share/vim/vim80/syntax/c.vim" line 1
/usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.0.1171/share/vim/vim80/syntax/c.vim
line 7: if exists("b:current_syntax")
>
Breakpoint in "/Users/muru/.vim/plugged/tagbar/plugin/tagbar.vim" line 1
/Users/muru/.vim/plugged/tagbar/plugin/tagbar.vim
line 21: scriptencoding utf-8
...
```

This doesn't restrict itself to ftplugins, but it does show which plugins will be loaded just by editing this file. The `breakadd` pattern can changed to something like `breakadd file */ftplugin/*.vim` if you're only interested in files in an `ftplugin` directory somewhere.